# how to show a form only for admin in drupal

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

I create a module in drupal to show record in front end . Now i want to make a form so that admin can insert data . I tried to make a link with _menu() function but it is not working.

Here is my code

```
 function hello_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items['hellopage'] = array(

        'title'=>'My Hello Page',
        'description'=>'Hello users',
        'page callback'=>'mutual_output',
        'access callback'=>'user_access',
        'access arguments'=>array('access content'),
        'type'=>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM        
    );
    $items['gethello'] = array(
        'page callback'=>'hello_ajaxCallHandler',
        'access callback'=>'user_access',
        'access arguments'=>array('access content'),
        'type'=>MENU_CALLBACK       
    );

    $items['admin/config/people/hello'] = array(
      'title' => 'hello module',
      'description' => 'Configuration for the hello module.',
      'page callback' => 'show_hello_form',
      'page arguments' => array('access content'),
      'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    Return $items;  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display it in a block or in a page? Maybe you could place this form in the configuration page of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. 
apart from the 'page arguments' line in the admin/config/people/hello
But that shouldn't break anything

Could you define what you mean with not working? 
The hook menu array is cached so you'll need to flush the caches every time you change anything.